# Missing some input keys in langchain even though it's present

Tags: python, langchain

Why does the below code complain that extra_instructions is a missing key, even though it's learning included in input_variables=["context", "question", "extra_instructions"]?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
vectorstore = Chroma(
    collection_name=collection_name,
    persist_directory=chroma_db_directory,
    embedding_function=embedding,
)

prompt_template = """

{extra_instructions}


{context}


{question}

Continuation:
"""

PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    template=prompt_template,
    input_variables=["context", "question", "extra_instructions"],
)

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(
        search_kwargs={"k": 1}
    ),
    chain_type_kwargs={"verbose": True, "prompt": PROMPT},
)
```

Comment: can you please paste the complete code and error message?